# Facebook Live Video API, can I share a friend video stream programmatically?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I want to share a Facebook video live stream on my own wall programmatically. I want to do it inside my app after a Facebook login made with the `facebook sdk`, something like a normal link sharing:

```
 NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [params setObject:link forKey:@"picture"];
 [params setObject:LinkStringa forKey:@"link"];
 [params setObject:ShareTextView.text forKey:@"message"];
 [params setObject:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString] forKey:@"access_token"];

  FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                parameters:params
                                HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {

      // Handle the result
      if (!error) {



      }
      else{
          NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);
      }

  }];
```

I can't find mentions about sharing live video on Facebook documentation, only how create and publish live video. How can I share a live stream video?

Comment: What link are you using in your above code and what is not working? A live video is basically just a "post" so you should be able to share the link to that post

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method for that:

```
- (void)enableFacebookLiveStreamingWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSString* facebookStreamURL, NSString* facebookStreamKey, NSError* error))completionHandler;
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:permissionPublishActions])
        {
            NSString* liveVideosRequestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/live_videos",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID];
            FBSDKGraphRequest* request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:liveVideosRequestPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].permissions);

                if (error)
                {
                    if (completionHandler)
                        completionHandler(@"",@"",error);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (completionHandler)
                        completionHandler(@"rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/",[[result objectForKey:@"stream_url"] lastPathComponent],nil);
                }

            }];
        }
    });
}
```

For streaming via RTMP use this open source library: https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore

There is a code for example:

```
self.vcSession = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(854, 480) frameRate:30 bitrate:1000000 useInterfaceOrientation:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.vcSession.previewView];
self.vcSession.previewView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 320, 240);//self.view.bounds;
self.vcSession.delegate = self;
[self.vcSession startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"your rtmp:URL "andStreamKey:@"your stream key"];
```

Comment: any other library rather than VideoCore?

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3

you can check this repo

https://github.com/hansemannn/facebook-live-ios

**How to use**

```
var liveVideo: FBSDKLiveVideo!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  
    // Create the live video service
    liveVideo = FBSDKLiveVideo(
        delegate: self,
        previewSize: self.view.bounds,
        videoSize: CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)
    )
    
    // Optional: Configure the live-video (see the source for all options)
    liveVideo.privacy = .me // or .friends, .friendsOfFriends, .custom
    liveVideo.audience = "me" // or your user-id, page-id, event-id, group-id, ...
    
    // Optional: Add the preview view of the stream to your container view.
    myView.addSubView(liveVideo.preview)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api which states:

" Stream a Live Video

Once a live_video object is created, a stream_url and key will be returned in the response. The server URL will be http://rtmp-api.facebook.com/rtmp/ and the stream key will be everything after it. Use both in order to push video frames through your streaming software."

Let me know how it turns out though as I'm also starting an app with this functionality.

Comment: That is just the URL your streaming software will need to use to send frames to Facebook, not a link you should use to share the stream on Facebook